Using input file name in expression for file output in QGIS
I'm trying to batch convert a few hundred NetCDF files to CSV.
I need the output file to be named based on the name of the input file or even the band name. But all I can get from the 'layer property' is something that resembles part of a 'layer' in a file and that is not unique.
Any ideas on how to get the file name? Or even order the files sequentially based on the order loaded into the interface? I just need a way of getting the date into the file name or the output CSV file from the GDAL2XYZ process


You can get the layer name with:
layer_property(layer:=@INPUT, property:='name')

Then extract the date part of it with:
regexp_matches(string:=layer_property(layer:=@INPUT, property:='name'), regex:='([0-9]{8})')[0]

([0-9]{8}) matches 8 digits, your date.
And concat this with an output path and file format:
Modify and Calculate By Expression:
concat('C:\\GIS\\GIStest\\Slope_',
    regexp_matches(
        string:=layer_property(layer:= @INPUT, property:='name'),
        regex:='([0-9]{8})'
        )[0],
    '.tif')



unfortunately this will not work. If you look at my example i realise that the 'layer' is actually the same name in every 'file' - I need either the file name or the band name :(

concat('C:\temp\wind\', regexp_matches(string:=  base_file_name( layer_property(layer:= @INPUT, property:='name')), regex:='([0-9]{8})')[0], '.csv') based on your code above does work to get the file name i need -> however every line gets the same file name when you "create values by expression" or add values by expression - am i doing something wrong?

I believe the answer given by @Bera covered most of this, but simply used the wrong property.
As you want the file name, and not the layer name, the property you are looking for is the path.
Simply using:
layer_property( @INPUT ,'path')

will yield the full path of the @INPUT raster layer.
You can then use that string to construct your new path.


I would suggest adding it as a comment or even extending @Bera's solution

(My answer was correct until OPs comment "i realise that the 'layer' is actually the same name in every 'file' - I need either the file name or the band name")
